# Found the same (BMVert) used multiple times

Tags: import

I'm trying to import the following .obj file into Blender

```
v -1.3433 0.3333 -0.7191
v -1.4807 0.3333 -0.3596
v -1.2747 0.0000 -0.8989
v -1.5493 0.0000 -0.1798
v -1.3433 -0.3333 -0.7191
v -1.4807 -0.3333 -0.3596
f 1 2 4 3 5 6
```

And getting the error specified above. When I switch the order of verts, it seems to be working. Any idea what causes this error and how can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

seems to me that's a malformed polygon:

[image]

Comment: So that's the problem? I just need to rearrange the vertices order to draw it properly with triangle strip?

Comment: what shape were you trying to draw?

Comment: I was trying to draw a hexagon.

Comment: yes the order of vertex indices is important. I'm not sure the error has much meaning when the input was describing malformed geometry. You are creating the .obj file yourself by hand/script?

Comment: Yes I was creating the .obj with a script. For some reason I thought I need to order vertices for triangle strip. Once I just arranged them in normal order it started working perfectly

Thanks!